# Start node server from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to start a node service directly from flutter application this is my code

```
Process.run(
   'pm2',
   ['start', 'bin\www'],
   runInShell: true,
   includeParentEnvironment: true,
   workingDirectory: 'E:\Works\PosApi\posapi',
 ).then((result) {

   print("server started");
   // print(result.pid);
 }).catchError((err) {
   print(
       "node start- cath err");
 });
```

please tell me how to use **process.run()**  properly

previously I used

```
std::string start = base_directory + "\\node\\nodestart.bat";
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open",start.c_str(), NULL,NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

in main.cpp/wWinMain()
and in that bat file added '*cd /d E:\Works\PosApi\posapi & pm2 start bin/www*' that was working fine.

Comment: In your code, there are backslash characters "\" in your string literals. You should either double them (ie: 'bin\\www') or use a raw string literal (r'bin\www')

Comment: @Xavier thanks but not working for me

Comment: What is the error message printed? If you print the error message with: print("node start- cath $err");

Comment: @Xavier no error message. function return in success. but node not starting